# Elasticsearch sort inside top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of messages where I store `messageHash` for each `message` too. I also have many more fields along with them. There are multiple duplicate `message` fields in the index e.g. "Hello". I want to retrieve unique messages.

Here is the query I wrote to search unique messages and **sort them by date**. I mean the message with the latest date among all duplicates is what I want 
to be returned.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "message": "Hello"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "top_messages": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "messageHash"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_messages_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              },
              "_score"
            ],
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that it's not sorted by date. It's sorted by doc_count. I just get the sort values in the response, not the real sorted results. What's wrong? I'm now wondering if it is even possible to do it.

EDIT:

I tried subsituting `"terms" : { "field" : "messageHash",  "order" : { "mydate" : "desc" } } ,  "aggs" : { "mydate" : { "max" : { "field" : "date" } } }` for `"terms": { "field": "messageHash" }` but I get:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Found two sub aggregation definitions under [top_messages]",
        "line" : 1,
        "col" : 412
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Found two sub aggregation definitions under [top_messages]",
    "line" : 1,
    "col" : 412
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```